# scp to AWS EC2 - error - "Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root"."

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, file-sharing, scp

I'm trying to scp a file to /var/www because I'm playing with apache. To move the file I do `scp -i <ec2-shh-key> localfile root@<ec2-instance-ip>:/var/www/fileremote`.

But this gives me an error:

`Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".`

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: I have discovered [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/138893/scp-to-remote-server-with-sudo) which answers the question by first scp'ing the file to a non-sudo dir, then passing a sudo mv command over ssh to move the file. Is there no way to do this in one step with just scp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the error you list then you are not specifying "ubuntu@" in the scp command, or you have copied the /root/.ssh/authorized_keys file to /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys (which would be bad as you could then not log in with ssh).

It is true that once you do start specifying "ubuntu@" you will get a permissions error, but you can get around this using a command like this:

```
rsync -vazSHAX --rsync-path "sudo rsync" LOCALILE ubuntu@HOST:/var/www/REMOTEFILE
```

The key here is the --rsync-path option.

The rsync command will even let you copy whole directory trees as in:

```
rsync -vazSHAX --rsync-path "sudo rsync" LOCALDIR/ ubuntu@HOST:REMOTEDIR/
```

If you started the instance with a keypair generated by EC2 then you may also need to specify this option in rsync pointing to the local copy of the downloaded ssh key:

```
--rsh "ssh -i KEYPAIR.pem"
```

Here's an article I wrote about how to use sudo, ssh, rsync on Ubuntu EC2 instances:

> Using sudo, ssh, rsync on the Official Ubuntu Images for EC2
>   http://alestic.com/2009/04/ubuntu-ec2-sudo-ssh-rsync

Here's an article where I explain how to upload your default personal ssh key to EC2 so that ssh and rsync don't need extra identity options:

> Uploading Personal ssh Keys to Amazon EC2
>   http://alestic.com/2010/10/ec2-ssh-keys

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, I did make an error in my question -- I was in fact doing `root@<ec2-inst-ip>`; nevertheless, your answer solves my problem. Thanks for the good links.

Answer (score 1):

You can. Create a group, say "www-admin", add your username to that group, chown /var/www/fileremote to :www-admin, and chmod that path to allow group write.

Of course, if the path has been chown-ed to something else (non-default group), that group will lose all access. But in this case, just add your username to that group.

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for an answer to this problem as well.

In my case though I had incorrectly copied the `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys` to another account, instead of copying my intended `~ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

The root user `authorized_keys` file has a specific command in it that disallows connection.